# Text not displaying in the middle of circles in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The following code packs circles in d3js.

```js
csjson = {
  "children": [{
    "name": "DirtySprite",
    "count": 8833
  }, {
    "name": "LineSprite",
    "count": 1732
  }]
};

var diameter = 200;
var pack = d3.layout.pack().size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4]).padding(2).sort(function(a, b) {
  return Math.random();
}).value(function(d) {
  return d.count;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", diameter).attr("height", diameter);

var vis = svg.datum((csjson)).selectAll(".node").data(pack.nodes).enter().append("g");
var titles = vis.append("title")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }).text(function(d) {
    return d.children ? "" : (d.name + ' ' + d.count);
  });

var circles = vis.append("circle")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return !d.children ? "tan" : "beige";
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  });

var textLabels = vis.filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  }).append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

The circles form correctly however the labels are displaying on the upper-left corner of the screen rather than in the center of the circles.

```
var textLabels = vis.filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
}).append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
});
```

How to display the text in the middle of the circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are not setting the x and y value to the text DOM.

Instead of this:

```
var textLabels = vis.filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
}).append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
});
```

It has to be

```
var textLabels = vis.filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  }).append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle") .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
  });
```

working fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMEQGcVPvzucOMi1uBmG?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. The question seems dumb now! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the x and y position to the texts:

```
var textLabels = vis.filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
}).append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
}).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
}).text(function(d) {
    return d.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
});
```

This is just the generally principle, you may need to adjust x and y according to your needs.